# Java - DTO interface target.targetSource value null -> "some value"

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, dto

I'm using DTO interfaces to grab data from a custom Spring/Boot Repository method. The DTO is then used to pick up a real Entity. To further explain, here is my implementation:

```java
public interface ModuleEntityDTO {
    Long getId();
    String getReference();
    String getModuleName();
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface ModuleRepository extends CrudRepository<ModuleEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT U.id, U.moduleName, U.reference FROM ModuleEntity as U WHERE U.reference = :reference")
    ModuleEntityDTO getByReference(@Param("reference") String reference);
}
```

Once the `getByReference` method is called, I use the returned DTO to be able to grab a real implementation of an Entity, which is then passed to a Student object and saved to it:

```java
ModuleEntityDTO moduleEntity = this.moduleRepository.getByReference(module.getReference().toString());
Optional<ModuleEntity> fullModule = this.moduleRepository.findById(moduleEntity.getId());

if(fullModule.isPresent()) {
        targetEntity.setModules(fullModule.get());
        this.timeTableRepository.save(targetEntity);
    } else {
        throw new Exception(ErrorMessages.CANNOT_FIND_MODULE(module.getReference()));
    }
}
```

This is where things get weird; this call `Optional<ModuleEntity> fullModule = this.moduleRepository.findById(moduleEntity.getId());` blows up and returns the error: `The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!`

I thought this made sense, but when I started debugging further, I found this:

[image]

So we have `null -> "some value"`

What does this mean? Is it null? Is it not null? The runtime says null but the debugger says null and value. How would I go around getting this value? Could someone also explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adjust your repository implementation to return the entity as `Optional` value. In the service layer, null value assessment along with DTO conversion can be done with results.

```
Optional<ModuleEntity> module = moduleRepository.getByReference(id);

ModuleEntityDTO moduleEntity = module.map(moduleMapper::toDto).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(id, "Module not found"));

Optional<ModuleEntity> fullModule = this.moduleRepository.findById(moduleEntity.getId())
```